# Развертывание Telegram бота

Tags: java, mysql, sql, telegram-bot, azure

Доделываю telegram-бота (пишу на java) и тут у меня возник вопрос, даже не знаю как правильно его задать, совершенно в этом не разбираюсь! Где нужно его разместить, чтобы он постоянно работал, арендовать сервер? Виртуальную машину? Как это правильно назвать? Еще у меня есть база данных для хранения данных пользователя(MySQL), смогу ли я ее там поставить или нужно использовать сервисы по типу Microsoft Azure SQL? Не могли бы Вы, объяснить на пальцах как это должно работать. Может ссылку полезную скинете. И есть ли, ну а вдруг, бесплатные сервисы? Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один из самых распростаренных вариантов: арендуете vps сервер и устанавливаете на него java и mysql. Для того что бы было проще, можно поставить виртуальную машину себе, ОС например ubuntu server 16.04 / 18.04 или centos 7 / 8. Ставте без графической оболчки и тренируйтесь в настройке, как будете готовы, арендуйте сервер и переносите на него. Как правило vps с centos или ubuntu везде доступны, цены чуть ли не от 50-100 рублей начинаются за месяц.